# Does creating a nested model require new sub classes?

Tags: c#, viewmodel

I haven't worked much with modeling of data, and I've come up against something that seems strange to me.

My ViewModel looks like this

```
public class HomeIndexViewModel
{
    public Image ForSale { get; set; }
    public Image Sold { get; set; }
    public Image PrivateCollection { get; set; }

    public class Image
    {
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string ImageDescription { get; set; }
    }
}
```

but I find it strange to have to `new` all of the properties in order to prevent `null reference exceptions`

```
var hivm = new HomeIndexViewModel();
hivm.ForSale= new HomeIndexViewModel.Image();
hivm.Sold = new HomeIndexViewModel.Image();
hivm.PrivateCollection = new HomeIndexViewModel.Image();
```

Is there a smarter way to do this in order to to only have to use the first line?

```
var hivm = new HomeIndexViewModel();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use a default constructor ?

```
public class HomeIndexViewModel
{
    public Image ForSale { get; set; }
    public Image Sold { get; set; }
    public Image PrivateCollection { get; set; }

    // Default constructor
    public HomeIndexViewModel()
    {
       ForSale = new Image();
       Sold = new Image();
       PrivateCollection = new Image();
    }

    public class Image
    {
       public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
       public string ImageDescription { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then when you do

```
var hivm = new HomeIndexViewModel();
```

It will call the default constructor and initialize properties.

Or did I get something wrong ?

Comment: no, you didn't get anything wrong. My brain is just in holiday mode. Thanks.